# Deleting Contents of Multiple Directories, Only if They Exist (Batch File)

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to write a simple batch file that will clean up disk space. I have to delete the entire contents (folders and files) of 4 different directories, but only if they exist. I've been testing trying to delete one, but I know nothing about writing batch files. After all the research I've done, I came up with a couple lines of code that doesn't work.

```
@echo off
IF EXIST "C:\Windows\TestFolder\TestSubFolder\*.*"
DEL /s /q "C:\Windows\TestFolder\TestSubFolder\*.*"
for /d %%p in ("C:\Windows\TestFolder\TestSubFolder\*.*") do rmdir "%%p" /s /q
exit
```

In this scenario, I need to be able to delete the contents of TestSubFolder, if TestSubFolder exists. Whether it exists or not, after that action is complete, I need the code to do the same thing to a TestSubFolder2.

Thanks

Comment: So you want to delete the content of folders only if they exist; how do you delete their contents if the do not exist? or in other words: just delete their contents, without checking whether they exist...

Answer (score 1):

The main problem in your code is the improper usage of the `if` command. If there is only one command to execute if the condition is true, it can be written in the same line, but to write the command in the next line you need to use parenthesis. It should be something like

```dos
IF EXIST "C:\Windows\TestFolder\TestSubFolder\*.*" (
    DEL /s /q "C:\Windows\TestFolder\TestSubFolder\*.*"
    for /d %%p in ("C:\Windows\TestFolder\TestSubFolder\*.*") do rmdir "%%p" /s /q
)
```

But this can be simplified as

```dos
2>nul pushd "C:\Windows\TestFolder\TestSubFolder" && (
    rmdir . /s /q
    popd
)
```

That is, we try to change to the indicated folder (`pushd`) and if there was not any problem (conditional execution operator `&&` means execute next command if the previous one did not fail) them remove all the contents of the folder (`rmdir`) and return to the previous active directory (`popd`). The `2>nul` is just hidding any error message (ex. the folder does not exist, locked files that can not be removed, ...)

Now, if the process has to be repeated for more than one folder, we can use the `for` command to iterate over the list of the folders

```dos
for %%a in ( "folder1" "folder2" ) do ....
```

Placing the previous code into this `for` loop we have

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    2>nul (
        for %%a in (
            "C:\Windows\TestFolder\TestSubFolder"
            "C:\Windows\TestFolder\TestSubFolder2"
        ) do pushd "%%~fa" && ( 
            rmdir . /s /q 
            popd 
        )
    )
```

The error hidding has been moved to cover all the `for` execution, and now, for each of the folders (referenced by the `for` replaceable parameter `%%a`), we try to change to the folder using the full path (`%%~fa`) and if we can change to it, then remove all the folder contents before returning to the original active directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
CD "C:\Windows\TestFolder\TestSubFolder"
RD /s /q  "C:\Windows\TestFolder\TestSubFolder"
```

Works for me.

or from anywhere

```
RD /s /q  "C:\Windows\TestFolder\TestSubFolder"
MD "C:\Windows\TestFolder\TestSubFolder"
```